# Coding repeated measures 2x2 ANOVA for aligned rank transformed data

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, ranking

I'm using the following code to run a repeated measures 2x2 ANOVA after transforming my data using the `art` function from ARTool package for R using the following code:

`m <- art(response ~ Factor1*Factor2 + Error(Subjects/(Factor1*Factor2)), data=myData)`

and then

`anova(m)`

The art function performs alignment and ranking on the data. Does someone know if this is the correct way to account for repeated measures?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not the correct way, 
according to the examples of the [reference pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARTool/ARTool.pdf) the right way should be:

```
m <- art(response ~ Factor1*Factor2 + (1|Subjects), data=myData)
```

Just a hint, you also used the wrong line (/ instead of |)

Comment: The reference pdf says on page 4 that a repeated measures design should include an error term, "as in `y ~ a*b*c + Error(d)`," but to me it's not clear that the d in Error(d) is meant to be identical to the d in (1|d) recommended for mixed effect ANOVAs. I chose the error in the original post after reading this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/two-way-anova-with-repeated-measures/)

Comment: The HigginsABC example on page 10 of the document you reference has an example with the `Error` notation, so it appears either notation is permissible.